# findAll from org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository returning duplicates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So I have repository defined as follows:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>
```

My entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="PERSON_GENERATOR", sequenceName="PERSON_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PERSON_GENERATOR")
private Long id;

@Column(name="ssn")
private String socialSecurityNumber;

private String name;
public Person() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

I have ommitted the getters and setters for socialSecurityNumber and Name. In the database there are 1000 records.

I have a Spring bean annotated with `@Component` that uses the PersonRepo by calling its `findAll()`. When `findAll()` gets called I get the list of 1000 records with their UNIQUE ID however, when I loop through the list of Persons returned by `findAll()` I find unexpected results.

```
@Component
public class PersonComponent {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepo;

    public void printPerson() {
        List<Person> people = personRepo.findAll();
        for(Person person : people) {
            System.out.println("id=" + person.getId() + ", ssn=" + person.getSocialSecurityNumber() + ", name=" + person.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

So if in my db i have the records

```
id, ssn,  name
 1, ssn1, Bob
 2, ssn2, Mary
 3, ssn3, Joe
```

when I call the `findAll()` I constantly get this back

```
id=1, ssn=ssn1, name=Bob
id=2, ssn=ssn2, name=Mary
id=3, ssn=ssn2, name=Mary
```

Notice that i get the correct Ids (ie. 1, 2, 3) but for some reason id 3 is mapped to ssn2,Mary and NOT ssn3, Joe

This behaviour happens only after the first call to `findAll()` (ie. the first findAll, works fine but subsequent once show the behaviour explained above). In other words, when the application starts up and the Spring bean that uses the PersonRepo gets called for the first time, `findAll()` seems to work fine. But when a subsequent call is made to the Spring Bean then findAll behaves as described.

Lastly, When i call the web service http://localhost/persons (which calls `findAll() under the covers) I get the correct behaviour every time.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your code which prints the values? I suspect you are using wrong variable to print the values.

Comment: @AkhileshSingh , I just added the PersonComponent class that prints out the id, ssn and name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably relating to omitting getters and setters for name and social security variables ? After all those are declared private so we need a way to access them, hence why getters ?

I have replicated your app and if you use the following, you should not be getting duplicates at all.

Appllication.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/findall_db
spring.datasource.username=YOUR_DATABASE_USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD
```

Person Entity Java Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class PersonInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="PERSON_GENERATOR", sequenceName="PERSON_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="PERSON_GENERATOR")
private Long id;

@Column(name="ssn")
private String socialSecurityNumber;

private String name;



public PersonInfo() {
}



public Long getId() {
    return id;
}



public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
    return socialSecurityNumber;
}



public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String socialSecurityNumber) {
    this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
}



public String getName() {
    return name;
}



public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PersonInfo [id=" + id + ", socialSecurityNumber=" + socialSecurityNumber + ", name=" + name + "]";
}

}
```

Person Repository:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonInfo, Long>{

}
```

Person Controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonInfoRepository personRepo;


    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/people")
    public List printPersonInfo() {

           List<PersonInfo> people = (List<PersonInfo>) personRepo.findAll();

           System.out.println(people.toString());

    return people ;

}   


}
```

Comment: Yes, i tried to do that, but then i realized that they aren't per se duplicates because if you notice when i call findAll() i get back ids 1,2,3. The problem is that for some reason, id 3 says that it has snn value of 'ssn2' and name a value of 'Marry'

Comment: Ok, I have replicated the process and got it working with no duplicates. Try the update above out and let me know how it goes...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't omit the getters and setters in my application, I just ommitted them from the description here. So what I have is exactly what you have minus the controller, because I am using spring rest data as well

Comment: Have you tried my application files above? Those should work with no issues as I have tested them myself.

Comment: Yes, I did try it but with the same erroneous outcome. After a few days of troubleshooting I have found more information that changes the scope of the question. I think the issue has to do with the fact that data is being inserted and then extracted (by the findAll method) in the same transaction. Thank you for trying to reproduce

Comment: If you think my answer does somehow fixes the issue, please mark it as correct